# Getting Spring @Autowired and @postconstuct work

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I am trying to introduce a new bean to existing project

Current bean is

```
package w.x.y.z.pkgA
@Component
public class BeanA implements InterfaceA {

}
```

And I am trying to add new Bean to `w.x.y.z.pkgB`

```
package w.x.y.z.pkgB
public class BeanB implements InterfaceB {

    @Autowired
    private BeanA beanA

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructMethod() {
        //Call some method in BeanA
    }
}
```

From `BeanB` I want to access `BeanA` data and in `BeanB` post construct I want to register `BeanB` with `BeanA`. So I want to call `BeanA` method

And All these packages are packaged as jar
and spring context xml is

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="w.x.y.z.pkgA,w.x.y.z.pkgB" />
<bean id="beanb" clas="w.x.y.z.pkgB.BeanB"></bean>
```

But during deployment I get exception about bean in create state

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'context': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347)
at w.x.y.z.BeanA<init>(BeanA.java:25)
at w.x.y.z.BeanB.<init>(BeanB.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
```

I have also tried removed @Autowired and getting the `BeanA` object using `getBeanFactory().getBean(BeanA.class)`. But I get same error.

If I remove bean entry from xml file them it gets deployed properly but post construct is never called as it is no longer a bean.

`BeanA` is not dependent on `BeanB` at all. No references?

Is there a way to get this `@Autowired` and `@PostConstruct` to work when 2 beans are in same jar?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what could create the possible circular reference. One final thought: Remove the explicit bean definition in your context file, add a `@Component` annotation to the bean since it is already in the scope for component scan and let spring do its best :) (deleted my misleading answer)

Comment: Before posting it here I have tried it. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

You declare the bean as `<bean id="beanb" clas="w.x.y.z.BeanB">` from w.x.y.z package.

Try with

```
package w.x.y.z
@Component
public class BeanA implements InterfaceA {

}
```

```
package w.x.y.z
public class BeanB implements InterfaceB {

    private BeanA beanA

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructMethod() {
        //Call some method in BeanA
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

and

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="w.x.y.z" />
<bean id="beanb" clas="w.x.y.z.BeanB">
    <property name="beanA" value="beanA"/> <!-- Spring will create beanA as it is annotated with @Component -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Did you try to add <property name="beanA" value="beanA"/> in xml config and remove w.x.y.z.pkgB from component scan as there is nothing to scan.

Comment: Do you have a bean named `context`? Spring can not create this bean while initializing `beanA`

Comment: context bean is <bean id="context"
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">

Comment: No need to define `context` bean in spring xml configuration file. I give your code a try and it is working. check this https://github.com/ielatif/stackoverflow/tree/master/spring-standalone-sample